# How to center string in image with graphics?

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap

I am trying to write a string to a file and I want to center the string so it is in the middle.

I have this code so far :

```
    var title = "My title";
    var titleDescription = "My description";

    using (var image =
        Image.FromFile(
            @"path to image")
    )
    {
        var titleLocation = new PointF(image.Width / 2.0f, 30f);
        // var titleLocation = new PointF(image.Width / 2.0f - title.Length, 30f);
        var titleDescLocation = new PointF(30f, 50f);

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        {
            using (Font arialFont = new Font("Arial", 20))
            {
                graphics.DrawString(title, arialFont, Brushes.Black, titleLocation);

            }

            using (var arialFont = new Font("Arial", 10))
            {
                graphics.DrawString(titleDescription, arialFont, Brushes.Black, titleDescLocation);
            }
        }

        image.Save(Application.StartupPath + @"\new.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

I want the text of "title" to be centered in the image. My code is currently starting to write the text from the center and going to the right side. I need it to be perfectly aligned to the center.

Comment: Use graphics.MeasureString to get the width of the string, not the length of it in characters. WWWW is not the same as IIII

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I have tried this: `var stringSize = graphics.MeasureString(title, arialFont).Width;` and then `var titleLocation = new PointF(image.Width / 2.0f - stringSize, 30f);` but it wasn't centered still. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Simple maths.  if your string was 100, and your picture 200.. in your code you just did 200/2 = 100  so (100 - 100) = 0.. so it would be showing completely on the left. It should be 50 .. which is (200-100)/2 eg  (image.Width-stringSize)/2

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I kinda feel dumb. I appreciate your help and time. Feel free to post an answer if you wish to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was 2 fold

1. Using String.Length produces how many characters, not how wide the string is in terms of graphics. EG WWWW is not the same width as IIII in most fonts.
2. to center an object in another you take the size of the base object, subtract the size of the other object, and divide the remaining space in two. EG if your image is 200 wide and your string is 100, your original formula divided the image in two (so thats now 100) and then took the width of the string away, eg 100 so the answer was 0 .. not the 50 we would expect

so

You end up with

```
var stringSize = graphics.MeasureString(title, arialFont).Width;
var titleLocation = new PointF((image.Width - stringSize) / 2.0f, 30f);
```

You should also potentially check your string is smaller than the original image size.. but this will center it all the same.

Answer (score 2):

Use `StringFormat.Alignment`:

```
graphics.DrawString(
    title,
    arialFont,
    Brushes.Black,
    new Rectangle(Point.Empty, new Size(image.Width, 100)),
    new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Method called like this:

```
public void CenterString(Graphics g, string text, Font font, Color color, int width, int height)
{
    SizeF sizeF = g.MeasureString(text, font);
    using (SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(color))
    {
        g.DrawString(text, font, solidBrush, checked(new Point((int)Math.Round(unchecked(width / 2.0 - (sizeF.Width / 2f))), (int)Math.Round(unchecked(height / 2.0 - (sizeF.Height / 2f))))));
    }
}
```

and then you can call it like this:

```
CenterString(graphics, text, font, color, image.Width, image.Height);
```

Comment: You have quite a lot of code in there that you haven't explained at all.

Comment: Well, if I read correctly, he just said "I want" and "I need". and not "How to". I thought he just wanted a quick solution.

Comment: True, but remember, your answer isn't just for the person asking the question. Your answer should a source of information for the community as a whole. You should try to make it the best answer it can be, by explaining and documenting what it does.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried this: var stringSize = graphics.MeasureString(title, arialFont).Width; and then var titleLocation = new PointF(image.Width / 2.0f - stringSize, 30f);

you have to calculate like this:

```
var hCenter = (image.Width / 2.0f) - (stringSize/2.0f);
```